# ActiveRecord inside the thread is too slow

Tags: ruby, multithreading, activerecord

I have a problem. I have serveral code blocks that has to work parallel and independent, but can have some connection dots like threadsafe queue. I'm not using rails, that is just a ruby script. But i'm using activerecord. And when I'm calling an activerecord model find in the main ruby thread it is ok and selects are taking about 0.3 ms. But if I call an activerecord model find inside a created thread like:

```
Thread.new do
  3.times {
    SomeModel.find(3)
  }

end
```

It now takes 400 ms. Why does it happen and what to do, to low the request execution time?

Comment: The ActiveRecord connection pool may be too small. ActiveRecord defaults to a pool size of 5.  If an open connection is not available ActiveRecord will block waiting for a connection.  Try increasing your pool size by specifiying the pool: option in the connection parameters.

Comment: Which AR version are you using?

Comment: ActiveRecord version is 4.1.6. That is not pool problem, cos I already setted pool to 100. And making just 3 requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discivored that this is of ActiveRecord gets connection from a main thread, there it established the connection. Reestablishing connection in each thread does the trick. Another way is to override current_connection method in activerecord to share connection between the threads.

Comment: Do you mean that its waiting for a connection to become free? Or that there's some kind of synchronization lock going on?

Comment: Did got to deep in the problem yet, thinking about, but have no time for research, sorry... But that is something special about AR uses threads.

Comment: Alright, not sure I understand, but this is good to keep in mind. I have a feeling your question may get more attention in the future, so if you ever find out more information, I'm sure it would benefit many if you keep this updated. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I reread my comment, and... That looks like I was drunk when wrote it :) I wanted to say that I didn't go too deep in the problem. And thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Heh its alright, I understood that much at least. I just meant that I'm still curious about this behaviour. I guess I should have asked more specifically, what did you mean by *this is of ActiveRecord gets connection from a main thread*? That's why I asked about whether it was some kind of synchronization issue, because that's what that line sounds like to me. Can you elaborate on what that part of your post means?